# Tkinter label not updated with time

Tags: tkinter, time, label

I have copied the design for using a label to show data in other parts in the code where they just work fine. In this spefific label the time should be shown, but it doesn't update for some reason...does anyone know why

I do exact the same for other paramters and it works just fine. If I use print to see the value of cur_time it shows the time as it should. Yet the label isn't updated while all others are

I tried calling the time function in the assignment to TM_str directly

```
TM_str=StringVar()
TM_str.set('--')
#-------------------------------

labelTM=Label(myCanvas,textvariable=TM_str, width=14, fg=TM_COLOR, bg=CANVAS_BACKGROUND_COLOR,justify=LEFT,font=(TEXT_FONT, TEXT_VALUE_SIZE))

labelTM.place(x=(XWIDTH-110),y=Y_SENSOR_TYPE)

#------------
cur_time=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
TM_str=cur_time
print ("time:"+TM_str)
```

all other values update as they should, only time doesn't, that remains --

Comment: `TM_str.set(new_time)`, just like what you have done in your initial setup.

Comment: grrrr....sometimes my mind...I shouldn't program after midnight ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, for change the time you use:

```
TM_str=cur_time
```

but with this string you don't update time in stringvar but change the item in `TM_str`.

You hate to use the following string:

```
TM_str.set(cur_time)
```